# Object has no method 'Timepicker'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, timepicker

Currently I am working on a project with `bootstrap supr theme`. By default it is loading following js files :

```
bootstrap.js
colorpicker.js, date.js, elfinder.min.js, fullcalendar, iosorientation, jpages.min, jquery-ui, jquery-cookie, jquery-datatable, jquery-duallistbox, jquery-elastic, jquery-ibutton, jquery-imputlimiter, jquery, jquery-knob, jquery-lazyload, jquery-min, jquery-ui.button, jquery-ui.button, responsivetable, timepicker-addon etc.
```

Whenever in a page, when I am using timepicker in a page using the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#AcAppointments_start_time").timepicker({
        ampm: true,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
        stepMinute: 5,
    });

    $("#AcAppointments_end_time").timepicker({
        ampm: true,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
        stepMinute: 5,
    });
});
```

in console I am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'timepicker'`

What may be the possible reasons for this error ??

Update :

included js are

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/supr/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/supr/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/supr/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<!-- Load plugins -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/watermark/jquery.watermark.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/elastic/jquery.elastic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/inputlimiter/jquery.inputlimiter.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/ibutton/jquery.ibutton.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/stepper/ui.stepper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/color-picker/colorpicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/timeentry/jquery.timeentry.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/select/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/dualselect/jquery.dualListBox-1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/animated-progress-bar/jquery.progressbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/pnotify/jquery.pnotify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/lazy-load/jquery.lazyload.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/jpages/jPages.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/pretty-photo/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/smartWizzard/jquery.smartWizard-2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/ios-fix/ios-orientationchange-fix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/elfinder/elfinder.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/plupload/plupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/plupload/plupload.html4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/plupload/jquery.plupload.queue/jquery.plupload.queue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/plugins/responsive-tables/responsive-tables.js"></script>
<!-- Important Place before main.js  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/supr/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/supr/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/supr/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/supr/appointpressjs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you include the jqueryui js file?

Comment: yep jquery-ui.min.js is included ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you included your timepicker.js(whatever) before this code chunk and after the UI core js? Basically you need to add the dependency first for timepicker.js, then the timepicker js itself and then the code chunk. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to change the order of the jquery, but in console, I can see that the timepicker.js is being loaded before jquery and jquery-ui How can I set the dependency ?

Comment: Can you get me the code snippet how you've included the libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Browser console told you that browser can't find timepicker plugin. 
Which is mean that you didn't include you timepicker plugin properly.

As I know there is no timepicker component in bootstap. You should use some 3-party plugin.
Like this http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

Check that is timepicker script exists in your script folder.
Check that you have added script tag with timepicker after you connected bootstrap script

Comment: We are using php timepicker assets with slider, timepicker assets is being loaded but it is being loaded after jquery-ui, how can I change the order of them ?